# SSO between Moodle and Azure AD

Tags: single-sign-on, moodle, azure-active-directory

I want to integrate Moodle with Azure Active Directory to support SSO. I don’t have Office 365.  Whether Office 365 is mandatory for SSO With Azure AD?

Moodle Version : 3.2.1